# Very simple jQuery accordion, not $(this)

Tags: jquery, accordion

I have fiddle made: http://jsfiddle.net/SFKhh/

Its a simple Accordion, but i'm trying to avoid when the user clicks on the currently open header, for it to break. Ie. this line `$('.accContent').slideUp();` i was thinking of doing this: `$('.accContent')!$(this).slideUp();` that sort of thing (i know the last piece of jQuery is wrong)

Comment: BTW, you probably mean `.nextAll('.accContent:first')` rather than `.next('.accContent')` (which returns nothing if the next element isn't `.accContent`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check whether the corresponding content block is already showing. If so, do nothing by immediately returning and jumping out of the click handler.

```
var $content = $(this).next('.accContent');
if ($content.is(':visible')) return;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/geertdd/SFKhh/4/

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to write

```
$('.accContent').not(this)
```

**EDIT**: You don't want to exlucde `this`; you want to exclude the content.

```
$('.accContent').not($(this).next('.accContent'))
```

Comment: hmmm indeed, but it still slides down the current slide?

Comment: @benhowdle89: Presumably you are calling this inside the `.click()` routine, so `this` is an object with the `.accContent` class, and will thus be part of the set filtered?

Answer (score 0):

I did this example for a user on another forum, it may help you also: http://jsbin.com/olezib/edit#javascript,html,live